# Does $\nabla_X Y-\nabla_Y X$ satisfy the Jacobi identity?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Assume that $\nabla$ is an arbitrary connection on a manifold.
Under what conditions, other than LC connections, the binary operator $\nabla_XY -\nabla_YX$ defines a Lie braket on $\chi^{\infty}(M)$?

If it is  not true  for  a  general  connection, is there  a name  for  this property  of  connection?

What  is  an  example or  non example  of    a  connection $\nabla $, with non trivial torsion,  for  which $\nabla_XY -\nabla_YX$  satisfy or dissatisfy the  Jacobi  identity?

Comment: What does $\nabla_X^Y$ mean? If you mean to refer to the covariant derivative of $Y$ in the direction $X$, that's usually written $\nabla_X Y$.

Comment: @JackLee  Dear Professor  Lee, Thank  you  for  your  comment. I fix it.

Comment: Since the space of linear connections is affine, it's no loss to write $\nabla = D + A$ for some fixed torsion-free background connection $D$ and look for an appropriate $(1,2)-$tensor $A$. I think imposing the Jacobi identity will give you a first-order PDE for the antisymmetric part of $A$; i.e. the torsion of $\nabla$.